# unable to remove class using ext js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to remove a class as below but its not working.

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.select('div').on('click', function () {
        Ext.get('div').removeClass('tst2');
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zhvKn/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass [`Ext.get`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext-method-get) the id of the node or a DOM Node or an existing Element.

You can do it like this:

```
Ext.select('div').on('click', function () {
    Ext.get(this).removeCls('tst2');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vGLQt/1/